# Hazelcast cluster to cluster communication

Tags: hazelcast

I want to setup hazelcast clusters.

One way to do that is creating individual instances of haxelcast server on different machine and define the members (other hazelcast servers) where existing nodes of Server instances are running.

I am using replicated Map so across the cluster all the servers will have the same copy and not partitioned.

But if want to ensure across clusters same replicated map to work and have same copy ,how can we do that ?

Also how do ensure cluster to cluster communication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if want to ensure across clusters same replicated map to work and
>   have same copy ,how can we do that ?

If all you want to do is check if the write is updated in all the nodes, you can monitor the clusters using Hazelcast Management Center. More information on how to use management center is given [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.8.4/manual/html/Deploying_and_Starting.html)

> Also how do ensure cluster to cluster communication ?

In order for the clusters to communicate there are two discovery mechanisms provided by Hazelcast. One is multicast auto-discovery, where clusters do not need to know concrete adresses of other members, but they communicate using multicast. Another way is TCP/IP where you list hostname and IP addresses of the cluster members. You can check out the link [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Setting_Up_Clusters/Discovery_Mechanisms.html) to configure the network according to your suitability.

Comment: I have already gone through Hazelcast Management Center.It is paid version,i am looking for an free open source solution which works well with Hazelcast.

Comment: Unfortunately  Hazelcast Management Center is the only option which is available as of now. I'm not aware of any open source solution available. You can use map listeners available in Hazelcast manually to log entry of all the rows though.